# Different linespacing between title page and sections

Tags: fonts, spacing, fontsize, line-spacing

I need my document to have a linespace of 2, but not on the title. I tried customizing the `\baselineskip` command, but this changes the line spacing also on the title. I also tried `\fontsize{}{}` and `\linespread{}` on the title, but they have no effect in the line spacing. How can I have linespacing 2 **only** in the sections but not in the rest of the document (title, references, table of contents etc)?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 9in}]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}




\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{1cm}
        \Huge
        \textbf{Did IMF policies improve the economic conditions of low-income countries?}
       
        \vspace{0.5cm}
       
        \LARGE
        The Ghanaian case study
            
        \vspace{1.5cm}
            
        \textbf{Author Name}
            
        \vfill
            
        A thesis presented for the degree of\\
        Doctor of Philosophy
            
        \vspace{0.8cm}
            
            
        \Large
        Department Name\\
        University Name\\
        Country\\
        Date
            
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}


\section{Introduction}
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  It's permitted (and often desirable) to reset the baselines within the document itself.  So move that instruction out of the preamble, and place it after the title.

Comment: I tried moving the renewcommand after the end of the titlepage block, but it has no effect. Where should I put it?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

```
% spacingprob.tex  SE 579696

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 9in}]{geometry}
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{1cm}
        \Huge
        \textbf{Did IMF policies improve the economic conditions of low-income countries?}
       
        \vspace{0.5cm}
       
        \LARGE
        The Ghanaian case study
            
        \vspace{1.5cm}
            
        \textbf{Author Name}
            
        \vfill
            
        A thesis presented for the degree of\\
        Doctor of Philosophy
            
        \vspace{0.8cm}
            
            
        \Large
        Department Name\\
        University Name\\
        Country\\
        Date
            
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
% \the\baselineskip % prints the default \baselineskip 

% the ToC, etc

\setlength{\baselineskip}{24pt}
\section{Introduction}
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.

\clearpage
\setlength{\baselineskip}{12pt}

% references, etc
\end{document}
```